# how to load database mysql json array with php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to load this JSON data into my website with AJAX. What should I do?

**My HTML Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Authors</h1>
  <ul id="authors"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Ajax Code :**

```
function createNode(element) {
      return document.createElement(element);
  }

  function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el);
  }

  const xx = document.getElementById('authors');
  const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2';
  fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    let authors = data.results;
    return authors.map(function(authorz) {
      let span = createNode('span');

      span.innerHTML = '${authorz.gender}<br>';

      append(xx, span);
    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

This works as expected, but I want to change my link from

```
https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2
```

to

```
http://jiyo-hotel.com/ttm/mutiara.php
```

and

```
span.innerHTML = '${authorz.gender}'
```

to

```
span.innerHTML = '${authorz.kata}'
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `authorz.kata` or `authorz.data` ?

Comment: `authorz.kata` look link my json... thanks @LasVegasCoder